# how to make phpize run for xampp and not for other php instance

Tags: linux, xampp

I have two instances of PHP in my Ubuntu. One is xampp (/opt/lampp/bin) and the other is in /etc/php5. I want to install pecl extension for xampp php but every command i make it works only for /etc/php5

here's what I type:

1. cd imagick-3.1.0b1/
2. /opt/lampp/bin/phpize
3. ./configure
4. make
5. make install

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the --with-php-config option to the configure script to point it to the correct php-config5 binary, like so:

```
./configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/php5/bin/php-config5
```